# Doctrine in Symfony 2.1 : Fields, Columns and Indexes on multiple columns

Tags: symfony, doctrine, yaml, symfony-2.1

I'm quite new with symfony2 and doctrine and I've recently encounter an issue with indexes that I'm not able to fix.

Here is my experience.yml:

```
Test\PersoBundle\Entity\Experience:
type: entity
repositoryClass: Thibanir\PersoBundle\Repository\ExperienceRepository
table: experience
indexes:
    exp: 
        columns: [slug,company_id,begin_date,end_date,is_current]
        type: unique
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    type:
        type: string
        length: 255
    begin_date:
        type: datetime
    end_date:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
    is_current:
        type: boolean
        default: false
    title:
        type: string
        length: 255
    description:
        type: text
    slug:
        type: string
        length: 255
manyToOne:
    company:
        targetEntity: Company
        inversedBy: companies
        joinColumn:
            name: company_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

When I look at the index generated in mysql, I can see it, but the Unique flag is set to `False`

When I looked at the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/defining-models.html#adding-indexes) on creating index, the only difference I see with my syntax is that I inverted the keyword `Fields` and `Columns`. I did so because I learned it in this [tutorial](http://www.ens.ro/2012/03/27/symfony2-jobeet-day-3-the-data-model/).

If I try to invert the two keywords to match this syntax:

```
indexes:
    exp: 
        fields: [slug,company_id,begin_date,end_date,is_current]
        type: unique
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
columns:        
    type:
        type: string
        length: 255s:
    [...]
```

when I issue `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` I get the following error :

```
[ErrorException]                                              
Notice: Undefined index: columns in /home/test/Project/perso/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/YamlDriver.php line 199
```

Here are my two questions :

1. What is the difference between fields and columns in Doctrine ( I
   couldn't find the answer on their website)?
2. How do I create a unique index on multiple columns?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference between fields and columns
Field is the name of the property in the entity. Column is the name of the column in the SQL table. For example,

```
createdAt:
      type: datetime
      column: created_at
```

Here, the property name in the entity will be createdAt and the column name in the SQL table corresponding to that entity will be created_at. If you don't specify the column, then the column name in the SQL table will be same as the property name. In this case, createdAt.

To create unique index on multiple columns, specify

```
unique:true
```

for each of the fields.
Example:

```
socialId:
  type: bigint
  column: social_id
  unique: true

playerId:
  type: bigint
  column: player_id
  unique: true
```